# Throwing a derived class object stored in a base class pointer

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class

I would like to throw a derived object as a type of exception. The memory for this derived object was allocated dynamically and the object is managed by a base class pointer. This base class is abstract. When I try to throw the de-referenced pointer, it gives me an error `object of abstract class type is not allowed`. I understand this error is neccessary so that you are forbidden from throwing an object of the abstract base class. However, I wonder if there is any way of being able to throw the derived object stored in the base class pointer. The derived object is of course not abstract. Given it is common to use base class pointers to perform polymorphism, I have a feeling there should be a way around it. Is there any? I would rather avoid having to throw the pointer itself. Specially given it is a unique pointer and I suppose it would give me an error if I caught the smart pointer and hence had two copies.

Comment: Did you try simply throwing the pointer instead? Did you try defining an abstract virtual method in the base class, and implementing it in the derived class by throwing itself?

Comment: You probably don't want to throw the dynamically allocated object anyway. The clean-up can get messy. If you add a [mre] of your code we can give you better tailored advice and probably even an answer.

Comment: I don't believe there's any way around the fact that the `throw` site has to know the actual type of the object being thrown. You want to throw the copy of the object you hold, which means the compiler needs a means to make that copy, and at the very least it needs to know how much memory to set aside to hold it.

Comment: Yea that makes sense. Thank you all! I will just throw one of the members of the derived object

Comment: Something like [this](https://onlinegdb.com/SJDeWs7KL) might work, or also [this](https://onlinegdb.com/rJdVboQKI), if you don't want to play with pointers.

Comment: @Chipster I wonder if the first example is a memory leak? I am surprised you can allocate memory on the throw statement. I guess as long as you did ```delete Base``` in the catch block you would be fine. I think that is actually a great suggestion to my problem in question. I could copy-construct a derived object to be able to throw it. It looks to me a bit overkill though. Your second example I'm aware of but it doesn't really help my situation. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried casting the pointer to the derived type using `reinterpret_cast<DerivedType *>(pointerToAbstractBaseClass)` before `throw`ing it?

Comment: @Luismi98 Yes, I think it was, actually. I realized that after I hit send. You might be able to delete it in the `catch`, though. It was just a suggestion. I think I personally like the second one better.

Comment: @Rotartsi That's an interesting suggestion. I didn't know you could do that. If it works that would actually be the best answer to my question.